# "Copy to ouput directory" doesn't work like I thought

Tags: debugging, build, visual-studio-2013, output-directory

This question is probably asked thousand times, but no answer helped me. I added a XML file to my project and wanted it to be copied into the output directory when I debug/build the project. So I set "Copy to ouput directory" to "Copy always", but Visual Studio/Compiler doesn't copy the file into the output directory. **How can I make Visual Studio copy the file into the output directory when I debug/build?**

[image: Screenshot of my project]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the Build Action (Buildvorgang) to Content or None

Comment: It worked! I know that None makes nothing, but where is the difference to Content?

Comment: Some explain here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197609/copy-to-output-directory-for-images-not-working-visual-studio-2010